# Selecionar Item da lista pelo "ID" usando Thymeleaf e direcionar para outra página de detalhes

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Estou tentando montar uma aplicação utilizando SpringBoot, Hibernate and Thymeleaf.

Gostaria de pegar o "id" do servico selecionado na lista utilizando o Thymeleaf, buscar esse servico no banco de dados e então fazer o direcionameto para uma outra página que mostre os detalhes do serviço de acordo com o item da lista selecionado, porém estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null
```

View index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />      

</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
    <header id="home">
        <div id="serviceGalery">
            <div class="service" th:each="service : ${services}" >
                <p th:text="${service.name}"></p>
                <p th:text="${service.description}"></p>             
                <p th:value="${service.id}" ></p>
                <p th:text="${service.grade}"></p>

                <a th:href="@{/productdetail/{id}(id = ${service.id}) }">Buy</a>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </header>  
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Aparentemente estou conseguindo pegar o "id" do serviço selecionado com o Thymeleaf. Não sei se está correto mas pelo menos o id do serviço selecionado está aparecendo na URL da página "productdetail".

View `productdetail`:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h1>Product Detail</h1>

    <p>Name: </p>
    <p th:text="${service.name}"></p>
    </body>
 </html>
```

`Controller`:

```java
@Controller
public class ServiceController {

@Autowired
private ServiceRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {

    Iterable<Service> services = repository.findAll();

    model.addAttribute("services", services);

    return "index";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/productdetail/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String productDetail(@PathVariable("id") Long serviceId) {

    Optional<Service> service = repository.findById(serviceId);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("service", service);

    System.out.println("teste: " + serviceId);

    return "productdetail";
}
```

Modelo:

```java
package com.markus.getachef.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name="servico")
public class Service {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String grade;
private String description;

public Service() {

    public Service(String name, String grade, String description) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.description = description;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }
    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Alguém pode me mostrar qual é a forma correta de fazer isso?

Comment: Você tá mandando um `<Optional>` para a `view`: `Optional<Service> service = repository.findById(serviceId);``, por isso não acha o `getter` para `name`

Comment: Denis Souza, sou iniciante na linguagem, nao entendo muito bem o que isso quer dizer, tem como me explicar? Eu so coloco o <Optional> porque ele me da um erro quando uso repository.findById(serviceId); e pede pra alterar de Service para Object

Comment: Dá uma olhada [aqui](http://blog.caelum.com.br/chega-de-nullpointerexception-trabalhe-com-o-java-util-optional/), mas pode ser problema em outra parte do código

Answer (score 0):

Para acessar os elementos dentro de um OPTIONAL é diferente de uma LIST. Para que você tenha acesso aos elementos do OPTIONAL tenta na linha seguinte adicionar o .get().

```
modelAndView.addObject("service", service);
```

E vai ficar assim

```
modelAndView.addObject("service", service.get());
```